# Insert into Database records only with test run. Spring boot

Tags: database, spring-boot

Is it possible to run `'data.sql'` file only when I am running tests on my Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to set up database before your test, here's how it's done https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-integration-testing/